# Ruby on Rails: polymorphic many-to-many design?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many, polymorphic-associations

I'm having troubles getting a polymorphic many-to-many model working in ruby/rails. The model has three tables that need to be joined, Infection, Drug, and Symptom:

```
create_table "diseases" do |t|
    t.string     "name"
end

create_table "drugs" do |t|
    t.string     "name"
end

create_table "symptoms" do |t|
    t.string     "name"
end

create_table "to_symptoms" do |t|
    t.integer    "symptom_id"
    t.integer    "symptomatic_id"
    t.string     "symptomatic_type"
end
```

Where symptoms is linked to both infections and drugs.  The tricky part is that the relationship of a symptom to a drug can be either as a side effect or as a contraindication.  The way I tried to do this was:

```
class ToSymptom < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :symptomatic, :polymorphic => true    
    belongs_to :symptom
end

class Drug < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :to_symptom, :as => :symptomatic

    has_many :contraindications, :class_name => "Symptom", 
             :through => :to_symptom, :source => :symptomatic, 
             :source_type => 'Contraindication'
    has_many :side_effects, :class_name => "Symptom", 
             :through => :to_symptom, :source => :symptomatic, 
             :source_type => 'SideEffect'
end

class Symptom < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :to_symptom

    has_many :diseases, :through => :to_symptom, :source => :symptomatic, 
             :source_type => 'Disease'
    has_many :contraindicated_drugs, :class_name => "Drug", 
             :through => :to_symptom, :source => :symptomatic,
             :source_type => 'Contraindication'
    has_many :caused_by, :class_name => "Drug", :through => :to_symptom, 
             :source => :symptomatic, :source_type => 'SideEffect'
end

class Disease < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :to_symptom, :as => :symptomatic
    has_many :symptoms, :through => :to_symptom
end
```

The Disease <-> Symptom relationship seems to be working the way I'd expect, but the relationships between Drug and Symptom aren't doing what I'd expect.  The relationship in the direction of symptoms-> drugs seems to be working, but the reverse direction generates some weird SQL.  If I try something like:

```
d = Drug.first
d.contraindications
```

I'll get the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    `symptoms`.* 
FROM `symptoms` 
INNER JOIN `to_symptoms` ON `symptoms`.`id` = `to_symptoms`.`symptomatic_id` 
WHERE `to_symptoms`.`symptomatic_id` = 2 
    AND `to_symptoms`.`symptomatic_type` = 'Drug' 
    AND `to_symptoms`.`symptomatic_type` = 'Contraindication'
```

The `to.symptoms.symptomatic_type = drug` shouldn't be in there, and the join in on the wrong field of `to_symptoms` (`symptomatic_id` vs. `symptom_id`.  I've tried a ton of different combinations, but I can't seem to get this one to work.  Is what I'm trying to do even possible in RoR?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this isn't very widely advertised, but it apparently doesn't work in Rails... (polymorphic mas_many :through)  (at least not without insane hacks).  I'll try to find some supporting links

Comment: Hmm, that might explain why I couldn't find any example of it working online.  I can get around accessing those by defining functions like `  def contraindications
    Symptom.joins(:to_symptom).where(:to_symptoms => {:symptomatic_id => self.id, :symptomatic_type => 'Contraindication'})
  end
` but it would still be nice to have a faster way of building up those linkages.  Can you give me any hints to overload the << operator so something like `d.contraindications << Symptom.create(...) ` would work?  Or would I need to create a class Contraindication to have any chance at that?  Thanks again!

Comment: Ovverloading the operator :http://strugglingwithruby.blogspot.com/2010/04/operator-overloading.html  bottom of the page shows an example for "<<".  I'm not totally following how that will help your problem though.  So far, I haven't found a good clean solution for this thing myself